# Add customize text at the bottom pdf invoice magento

Tags: magento

I need help on how to Add customise text at the bottom of magento pdf invoice.

Example "Thank you for working with us" at the bottom of the pdf invoice

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a module and overriding the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` class.  You can then copy the getPdf() method to your new class and add make your changes to the end of each invoice (make sure to do this within the invoices loop since you can print multiple invoices at a time).

```
/**
 * Return PDF document
 *
 * @param  array $invoices
 * @return Zend_Pdf
 */
public function getPdf($invoices = array())
{
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();

    [...]

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {

        [...]

        /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
        }

        // Add your custom stuff here
        $this->insertMyCustomStuff();

    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}  

/**
 * Insert custom stuff to pdf page
 *
 * @param  Zend_Pdf_Page $page
 * @param  Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract $invoice
 * @return Zend_Pdf_Page
 */
public function insertMyCustomStuff($page, $invoice)
{
    $page->drawLine(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y); //right
    $this->y -= 25;
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Thank you for working with us!'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
}
```